# CSS overlay via visibility - links in overlay not clickable on mobile devices

Tags: css

Please have a look at the following [codepen](http://codepen.io/dotcs/pen/LERGyw).

For users on the desktop, the example works as expected. If the image is hovered the overlay is shown and the link can be clicked.

But on mobile devices I have some problems with this solution. What I want is that a click on the image shows the overlay. The second link should then target the external page. This works fine as long as one clicks on the bottom of the image, but it stops working when clicking the top of the image (in the region where the link is in the overlay).

If I understand things correctly this is because the overlay is shown instantaneously which means that the link is also visible and clickable instantaneously. So the question is how to force the example to first show the overlay and THEN activate the link.

*Side note*: I cannot use solutions where the overlay is shown via `display: none` and `display: block`, because in my real case the overlay defines the size of the complete box, but this is not important for this example and would make things more complicated.

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: Have you tried messing with the z-index of your overlay/link layer? Also, you can't do hover effects on a mobile device which might be part of your problem.

Comment: Well, I use the `:active` pseudo class to simulate hover on mobile devices. This works fine for Android devices, but still needs some work on iOS devices. There a solution should be to work with empty `onclick` attributes. Have a look [here](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/hover.html). I think the `z-index` does not help a lot here, does it?

Comment: How about the `pointer-events: none;` rule? add it to the overlay until it's visible and remove when shown. This should cause click events to fall through the overlay to the image below. EDIT: support may be flaky, see [this css-tricks post](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/)

Comment: You mean like [this](http://codepen.io/dotcs/pen/Kwgzpr). Unfortunately this does not work, even though the idea is good. Perhaps the only solution is to add a small delay to the `pointer-events: auto`, so that the link becomes clickable after this delay. On the other hand I always try to avoid javascript for actions like this.
And the browser support of this solution is not ideal (IE11+ only) as you have mentioned.

Comment: Okay, I have created a working example using a combination of `pointer-events` and jQuery. You can find it [here](http://codepen.io/dotcs/pen/raMeLB). The idea is to set `pointer-events: none` by default and use jQuery to rewrite that to `pointer-events: auto` with a short delay. I wonder if the same idea can be accomplished without the use of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This snippets will enable hover effects for touchscreens

[Preview / Demo](https://codepen.io/deanvangreunen/pen/eYYJoWb)

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {}, true);
```

and add `aria-haspopup="true"` and `onclick=""`

```
<div class="overlay" aria-haspopup="true" onclick="">
    <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Testlink to Google</a>
  </div>
```

and this css `&:focus .overlay`

```
&:hover .overlay, &::focus .overlay, &:active .overlay {
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

Comment: **Note:** tested on mobile.